# shmat(3) function returns 0xffffffffffffffff address

Tags: c++, c, shared-memory

I have been struggling with using IPC shared memory. I am trying to write simple server / client programs communication through BSD TCP Sockets. The server is multithreaded and services multiple parallel chess duels between users. Each thread is associated with only one user. To share data about moves and duel status I want to use shared memory since the server controls almost everything.

I've created duel class and every time the duel request is accepted, the server creates new shared memory and pass the keys to Users:

```
this->key_kernel = (this->key_kernel + 17) % 1000000;
int shmid = shmget(this->key_kernel, sizeof(Duel), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

challenger->set_shmkey(this->key_kernel);
challenged->set_shmkey(this->key_kernel);

Duel *duel = (Duel *)shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);
duel->init_duel(challenger, challenged);
shmdt(duel);
```

When thread that controls communication notices the duel begins it does something similar:

```
shmid = shmget(current_user->get_shmkey(), sizeof(Duel), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
duel = (Duel *)shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);
```

And uses the duel methods. And it works okey, but... Up to five duels. I've noticed that every time, after 5 duels (ie. 5 duel accepts), no matter finished or in progress - the program fails (segmentation fault)

After investigating I've noticed that the duel pointer that should be attached to shared memory by shmat is at this point 0xffffffffffffffff. Also I have noticed some errno 24.

I'd appreciate even some sloppy fix like checking if the pointer is not 0xffff... but I don't really know if it is possible. Something like:

```
int *a;
a = nullptr;
if (a == nullptr) {...}
```

For nullptr it is easy, but I don't know how to cast a custom (i.e. Duel pointer) to a char* or something to compare it.

Comment: Open a terminal window and enter the `ipcs` command. What do you see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From man:

> shmat() returns the address at which the shared memory segment has been mapped into the calling process' address space when successful, shmdt() returns 0 on successful completion. Otherwise, a value of -1 is
> returned, and the global variable errno is set to indicate the error.

The `0xffffffffffffffff` pointer you see, is `-1` signifying error.

Add to your program an if which checks return values of `shmat` and `shmget` for errors. Inside the if you can use the `perror` function to print an error message that will tell you what went wrong.

This is a general rule. You should always check return values of system calls:

```
a = system_call_x();
if (a == (void*) -1) {
    perror("system_call_x failed, exiting");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank You, the errno is 24. Too many files opened sound a little bit vague to me though.

Comment: @Dr.Ske Again from man: `[EMFILE] The number of shared memory segments has reached the system-wide limit.`What it that system-wide limit? Of course it depends on the system.

Comment: That was it. When I have changed the SHMSEG the problem disappeared. However it sounds like a very non elegant solution so probably I'll try to solve it different.